# Prevent XKB layout switch vs shortcuts

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I use `setxkbmap` to define layout change shortcut as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>, as I am used to. But I face a problem sometimes that it clashes with shortcuts of the software I use, like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. How can I avoid changing layout when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+other_button? I use OpenSuse Linux with i3 wm.

Comment: Just came here with the same issue. Alas, I was really hoping this wouldn't be the accepted answer, but it is ... time to get used to a different key combo to change layouts I guess. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really a way around this if you want to use ctrl+shift to switch you layouts because ctrl+shift is now caught by xkb at a lower level than the applications you are using. I had the same issue and just switched to using both ctrls to change layout. Have a look at

```
$ grep 'grp:' /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst
  grp:switch           Right Alt (while pressed)
  grp:lswitch          Left Alt (while pressed)
  grp:lwin_switch      Left Win (while pressed)
  grp:rwin_switch      Right Win (while pressed)
  grp:win_switch       Any Win key (while pressed)
  grp:caps_switch      Caps Lock (while pressed), Alt+Caps Lock does the original capslock action
  grp:rctrl_switch     Right Ctrl (while pressed)
  grp:toggle           Right Alt
  grp:lalt_toggle      Left Alt
  grp:caps_toggle      Caps Lock
  grp:shift_caps_toggle Shift+Caps Lock
  grp:shift_caps_switch Caps Lock (to first layout), Shift+Caps Lock (to last layout)
  grp:win_menu_switch  Left Win (to first layout), Right Win/Menu (to last layout)
  grp:lctrl_rctrl_switch Left Ctrl (to first layout), Right Ctrl (to last layout)
  grp:alt_caps_toggle  Alt+Caps Lock
  grp:shifts_toggle    Both Shift keys together
  grp:alts_toggle      Both Alt keys together
  grp:ctrls_toggle     Both Ctrl keys together
  grp:ctrl_shift_toggle Ctrl+Shift
  grp:lctrl_lshift_toggle Left Ctrl+Left Shift
  grp:rctrl_rshift_toggle Right Ctrl+Right Shift
  grp:ctrl_alt_toggle  Alt+Ctrl
  grp:alt_shift_toggle Alt+Shift
  grp:lalt_lshift_toggle Left Alt+Left Shift
  grp:alt_space_toggle Alt+Space
  grp:menu_toggle      Menu
  grp:lwin_toggle      Left Win
  grp:win_space_toggle Win Key+Space
  grp:rwin_toggle      Right Win
  grp:lshift_toggle    Left Shift
  grp:rshift_toggle    Right Shift
  grp:lctrl_toggle     Left Ctrl
  grp:rctrl_toggle     Right Ctrl
  grp:sclk_toggle      Scroll Lock
  grp:lctrl_lwin_rctrl_menu LeftCtrl+LeftWin (to first layout), RightCtrl+Menu (to second layout)
  grp:lctrl_lwin_toggle LeftCtrl+LeftWin
```

These are all the different key combinations you can use to change the layout. I use `grp:ctrls_toggle` but you have a lot of options to play with and see what you like.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and worked out a compromise which wasn't immediately obvious from the accepted answer.

My layout switching was initially set to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>
and this interfered with my ability to use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd> shortcut to indent in nano / pico.

My compromise was to change the layout switching option from `grp:alt_shift_toggle` to `grp:lalt_lshift_toggle`. In other words, only pressing the *left* <kbd>Alt</kbd> and *left* <kbd>Shift</kbd> together change layouts, leaving, e.g. <kbd>(left) Alt</kbd> + <kbd>(right) Shift</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd> free to produce the desired indentation effect in pico.

In case it is useful to anyone, this is the full line I used in my `.fluxbox/startup` file:

```
setxkbmap -layout "gb,gr,ru" -variant ",,phonetic_winkeys" -option "grp:lalt_lshift_toggle" -model pc105 -rules evdev   # keyboard layout switching
```